# Clockify API Request Timeout when used with Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, clockify

At my company, we are using Clockify to track time.
Now, it's my job to extract the data from Clockify API and use it in a Power BI report.

To do this, I use a POST request for a Time Entries Detailed Report, so I get all the time entries.
However, there is a limit of a 1000 records when accessing this API.
To overcome this issue, I use a function that POST the request, which takes a pagenumber parameter and a second function that generates a list from 1 to x, where it loops through all the pages and stops when 0 time entries are returned for that page.
Code provided below.

This was working fine for a while, but more and more colleagues are tracking more and more time.
Therefor my query refresh fails more and more often, due to request timeout.
My hypotheses: looping through all the pages now takes too long.

Function:

```
fClockifyDetailedReport
= ( pagenumber ) => 
let
body = "{ ""dateRangeStart"": ""2023-01-01T00:00:00.000"", ""dateRangeEnd"": """&DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), [Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Culture="en-US"]) &""", ""detailedFilter"": { ""page"": """&Number.ToText( pagenumber )&""", ""pageSize"": ""1000"", ""options"": { ""totals"": ""EXCLUDE"" } } }", Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/{WORKSPACEID}/reports/detailed", [ Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"X-Api-Key"="{APIKEY}"], Content=Text.ToBinary(body) ]))
in
    Source
```

Loop to make the table:

```
tClockifyDetailedReport
= List.Generate(
()=> [pagenumber = 1, report = fClockifyDetailedReport(1)],
each not List.IsEmpty([report][timeentries]),
each [pagenumber = [pagenumber] + 1, report = fClockifyDetailedReport( [pagenumber])],
each[report
]
)
```

Is there any way to overcome this issue?
My solution would be a data warehouse to store the data, where data from previous months will no longer be refreshed, since they no longer change.
That way I only have to request the data for the current month, what will reduce the number of pages significantly.
Is there a way in Power Query to do this? Some way of only refreshing a part of the data?
Or do I need to use different software to extract the data to a data warehouse and get my data into Power Bi by accessing this data warehouse instead of the API directly?

Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> However, there is a limit of a 1000 records when accessing this API.

If your problem is your web request is getting rate limited, or a regular time out -- you can use [Value.WaitFor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/wait-retry)

Often APIs will return values in the response header that will say essentially 'you have X requests until time Y' or 'you hit the rate limit, you can resume
at time t' where 't' might be 10 seconds from now

### use `ManualStatusHandling`

If you don't, HTTP Status errors come back as exceptions. Instead, you probably want to capture `429`, `500`, `404`.

### Easier debugging

For testing you can use [httpbin.org/Status_codes](https://httpbin.org/#/Status_codes) to generate web Errors on demand.

### Try catch

You can use `catch` as syntactic sugar over the old `HasError` syntax.

- `e` is the `ErrorRecord`
- `e[Message]` returns the error as plain text.
- You can use logic on the message to change what you do, based on the error message.

If you just want the error as a text message, use `e[Message]`

```
= try Web.Contents(...)
    catch (e) => e[Message]
```

- See [HTTP Error codes @ mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

### A method to visually debug queries

[Here's a longer example that visually catches errors](https://github.com/ninmonkey/ninMonkQuery-examples/tree/96fd33ab255ceeccacc6f67048c9d2377ed6e21f/WebRequests#catching-webcontents-errors-using-and-manualstatushandling)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The StatusCode I get is 408: Request Timeout.

I don't have any information on what the rate limit is, unfortunaly.

I will look into implementing a wait for.
However, this will further slowdown my refresh, which already takes a lot of time.